# FluentBit unable to concatenate stack-trace logs for all the pods running on K8s node, it works only for a single pod on the node

Tags: kubernetes, newrelic, fluent-bit

We have been trying to configure fluent bit for logs aggregation on k8s cluster. We are using newRelic bundle helm charts to achieve this.
The newRelic bundle creates a pod on the each K8s cluster node, and processes the log based on the defined configuration.
Everything seems to be working fine except the stacktrace concatenation.
The problem is as follows:

We are running 4 pods on a single node, while running they create following log files under "/var/log/containers" directory.

```
myapp-svc1-<pod-id>.log
myapp-svc2-<pod-id>.log
myapp-svc3-<pod-id>.log
myapp-svc4-<pod-id>.log
```

Here is the config:

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     ${LOG_LEVEL}
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020
    
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              ${PATH}
        Parser            ${LOG_PARSER}
        DB                ${FB_DB}
        Mem_Buf_Limit     7MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10

    [FILTER]
        Name                      multiline
        Match                     *
        multiline.key_content     log
        multiline.parser          multiline-regex-error-trace

    [FILTER]
        Name           kubernetes
        Match          kube.*
        # We need the full DNS suffix as Windows only supports resolving names with this suffix
        # See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/#dns-limitations
        Kube_URL       https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
        Buffer_Size    ${K8S_BUFFER_SIZE}
        K8S-Logging.Exclude ${K8S_LOGGING_EXCLUDE}
    
    [FILTER]
        Name           record_modifier
        Match          *
        Record         cluster_name ${CLUSTER_NAME}
        Allowlist_key  container_name
        Allowlist_key  namespace_name
        Allowlist_key  pod_name
        Allowlist_key  stream
        Allowlist_key  message
        Allowlist_key  log
        Allowlist_key  kubernetes
   
    [OUTPUT]
        Name           newrelic
        Match          *
        licenseKey     ${LICENSE_KEY}
        endpoint       ${ENDPOINT}
        lowDataMode    ${LOW_DATA_MODE}
```

Here is the parser configuration that we have used:

```
  parsers.conf: |

    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name          multiline-regex-error-trace
        type          regex
        flush_timeout 1000
        rule      "start_state"   "/([0-9]{2,4}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}\,[0-9]{2,4}) (.*)/"    "stacktraceline2"
        rule      "stacktraceline2"          "/^([a-z]{1,10})\.(.*)/"                                                              "stacktraceline3"
        rule      "stacktraceline3"          "/^\s+at.*/"                                                                          "stacktraceline3"
    
    [PARSER]
        Name         docker
        Format       json
        Time_Key     time
        Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep    On
    
    [PARSER]
        Name cri
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
```

If we mention "/var/log/containers/*.log" for 'Path' key under 'INPUT' configurations, we are instructing fluenbit to collect all logs from that directoy, and process the same, and by god's grace it works perfectly.
However, the custom multiline parser "multiline-regex-error-trace" doesn't seem to work for all the pod logs in such a case.
The logs concatenate only for one of the pods and we see each stack trace line pushed separately for all the remaining pods.

To make this parser work for a specific pod we need to define path as "/var/log/containers/myapp-svc1-*.log"
OR "/var/log/containers/myapp-svc2-*.log" i.e. depending on pod name.
But this is not the desired configuration since defining pod specific paths will limit the log collection only for that pod on the node, and we need logs for all the pods.

Here is the log sample file:

```
2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service
    java.lang.Exception: Custom error
        at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at myapp.content.filter.RequestIdAddingFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestIdAddingFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We have tried using using multiline in-built fluentbit parser "java".  But it has another problem.
We have 3 types log lines in our stack trace.

```
**Line Type 1:**   2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service

**Line Type 2:**   java.lang.Exception: Custom error

**Line Type 3:**   
at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The in-built "java" parser seems to combine only the last 2 types "Line Type 2" and "Line Type 3", it excludes the first line.
The newrelic bundle internally uses fluent bit 1.9.4 which is the latest version as of today.
To replicate this issue, simply run 2 pods on a k8s node, and see if the stack traces are getting concatenated for each pod with fluent bit 1.9.4.
Make sure that log sample as mentioned above.
Could someone please help us out on the same, I have been banging my head against a wall for the past 7 days?

Comment: The first line is not _a known_ starting line of a multiline log record.
Is that the default log format of your app?
is the format of your container?
Do you have a simple app that reproduces this output?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your app is running in Kubernetes first you need to tell the Input Tail to [parse docker and CRI format](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/tail#multiline-and-containers-v1.8).
Example:

```
[INPUT]
    name              tail
    path              /var/log/containers/*.log
    multiline.parser  docker, cri
```

Then, if your your Java logs are not matched by the built-in `java` parser you can create your own [Multiline parser](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/multiline-parsing). Using your example I've introduced a couple of changes:

**parser.conf**

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-regex-error-trace
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    rule      "start_state"   "/^([0-9]{2,4}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}\,[0-9]{2,4}) (.*)/"  "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/^\s+([a-z]{1,10})\.(.*)/"                                                                    "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/^\s+at.*/"                                                                                   "cont"
```

Note: Remove your other custom parsers from `parsers.conf` to prevent them colliding with the built in parsers in Fluent-bit

**fluent-bit.conf**

```
[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Path              /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fluent-bit/2.2.2/etc/fluent-bit/test?.log
    Read_from_Head    On
    multiline.parser  docker, cri

[FILTER]
    Name                  multiline
    Match                 *
    multiline.parser      multiline-regex-error-trace
    multiline.key_content log

[OUTPUT]
    name  stdout
    match *
```

Note the `test?.log` pattern to capture 4 copies of the same log file

**test[1-4].log**

```
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000001Z stdout F single line...
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000002Z stdout F 2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000003Z stdout F     java.lang.Exception: Custom error (pod1)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000004Z stdout F         at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000005Z stdout F         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000006Z stdout F         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000007Z stdout F         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000008Z stdout F         at java...
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000009Z stdout F         at java...
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000010Z stdout F         at java...
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000011Z stdout F         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000012Z stdout F         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000013Z stdout F         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000014Z stdout F another line...
```

Result: Stack trace in a single event.

```
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [fluent bit] version=2.2.2, commit=, pid=48883
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [storage] ver=1.5.1, type=memory, sync=normal, checksum=off, max_chunks_up=128
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.6.6
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [ctraces ] version=0.4.0
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] initializing
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] storage_strategy='memory' (memory only)
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] multiline core started
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [filter:multiline:multiline.0] created emitter: emitter_for_multiline.0
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [input:emitter:emitter_for_multiline.0] initializing
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [input:emitter:emitter_for_multiline.0] storage_strategy='memory' (memory only)
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [output:stdout:stdout.0] worker #0 started
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
[2024/02/05 13:35:15] [ info] [filter:multiline:multiline.0] created new multiline stream for tail.0_tail.0
[0] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000001, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000001Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"single line..."}]
[1] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000002, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000002Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service
    java.lang.Exception: Custom error (pod1)
        at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java...
        at java...
        at java...
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"}]
[2] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000014, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000014Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"another line..."}]
[3] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000001, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000001Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"single line..."}]
[4] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000002, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000002Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service
    java.lang.Exception: Custom error (pod2)
        at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java...
        at java...
        at java...
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"}]
[5] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000014, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000014Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"another line..."}]
[6] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000001, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000001Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"single line..."}]
[7] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000002, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000002Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service
    java.lang.Exception: Custom error (pod3)
        at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java...
        at java...
        at java...
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"}]
[8] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000014, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000014Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"another line..."}]
[9] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000001, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000001Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"single line..."}]
[10] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000002, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000002Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"2022-09-02 18:46:53,206 ERROR 5d9073b1-9f90-42c1-b7a2-d5a6c13f2669 [http-nio-9002-exec-3] i.f.m.c.c.ContentController: Exception recevied from the service
    java.lang.Exception: Custom error (pod4)
        at myapp.content.controller.ContentController.throwError(ContentController.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java...
        at java...
        at java...
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"}]
[11] tail.0: [[1707138000.000000014, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-05T13:00:00.000000014Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"another line..."}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it jut placed in the wrong section?
in the [docs](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/multiline-parsing) they add the `multiline.parser` to the `INPUT` instead of to the `[FILTER]` section. Something like

```
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              ${PATH}
        Parser            ${LOG_PARSER}
        DB                ${FB_DB}
        Mem_Buf_Limit     7MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10
        multiline.parser  multiline-regex-error-trace
```